# Is "\n" not working in string.split for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, split

I have a external resource (raw text file) like:

```
1. Title 1
Content 1
|
2. Title 2
Content 2
|
3. Title 3
Content 3
```

I load them in a web page via AJAX and want to use content.split("\n|\n") to extract its content into an array for my use. But it seems it's not working.

What's weird is that **split("\n|")** works, but neither do **split("|\n")** nor **split("\n|\n")** work.

Comment: can you put you HTML code part here (ajax page code part)

Comment: can't reproduce your problem, are you sure the endings are `\n` not `\r\n`?

Comment: That's not weird. You're making an assumption about line endings that does not hold in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not JavaScript related. That's related to the operating system.

```
  var canonicalizeNewlines = function(str) {
      return str.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n');
  };
```

Basically DOS(Windows), FreeBSD and Unix systems use different white characters to end a line. `/r` is for DOS ,`/r/n` is for FreeBSD based(Mac). This will enforce a single style for all your new lines, the Unix default style which is `\n`.

Comment: Very nearly +1'd this, but I feel the OP could probably use, in it, an explanation of what this is all about